# Javascript not working when rendering a view using ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My structure looks like this

**head.blade.php**

```
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body class="page">
@include('layouts.sidepanel')
```

**sidepanel.blade.php**

```
div class="sidebar">
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-item" onclick="getPages({method: 'page',httpMethod: 'GET',uri: 'page',});">Page</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**foot.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**base-layout.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.head')


<main class="with-footer">

    <div class="row main-grid">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</main>
@include('layouts.foot')
```

the **controller**

```
public function getSettings() {

        $settings = DB::table('settings')->get();

        $returnHTML = view('settings')->with('settings', $settings)->render();
        if($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'data'=>$returnHTML));
        }
    }
```

**settings.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.base-layout')
@section('content')
<p>Test</p>
@endsection
```

and this javascript function

```
function getPages(params) {
    $.ajax({
        type: params.httpMethod,
        url: params.uri
    }).done(function (data) {
        switch (params.method) {
            default:
                if (data.success) {
                    if (data.data) {
                        $('.main-grid').html(data.data).fadeIn();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    })
}
```

Extending the base-layout inside settings.blade.php will duplicate the sidebar inside the main-grid class and the js is working but I don't want to another page inside settings exactly like the main, I just want the content and the js to work when rendering  it.

I've also tried **renderSection()['content']** but had the same results.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the `base-layout.blade.php` in this line `@extends('layouts.head')` it should be `include` instead of `extends` ?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if it's include or extends.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your function like this:

```php
$('#container_id').on('click', '.post_button, .btn_favorite', function () { });
```

It will work.